# How to list and update uploaded files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I have a Create page for Experiments and I also add file attachment when creating a new Experiment. On the other hand, I also want to edit the attachment as well Experimet on Edit page, but using the same file input control, I cannot listed the attached file. How to manage this? On the other hand, if the user change the attachment, is it possible to edit the previously saved file on the database, or should I delete the prior one with the same record Id?

Here is the code for Create:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <span class="btn green btn-file">
        <span class="fileinput-new"> Select file </span>
        <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
        <input type="file" name='files' multiple >
    </span>
    <span class="fileinput-filename"> </span> &nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:;" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> </a>
</div>
```

But have no idea to list the attachments on the Edit page :(

[image]

Comment: Any idea regarding to the problem???

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input (it can only be set by the user selecting a file to upload). You need to display the names of previously uploaded files in your view (probably with and associated 'Delete' button so the user can delete them). The file input can only be used to upload new files.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I am looking for a suitable example code from yesterday but still not found a suitable example. On the other hand, I also need a upload list for listing the newly uploaded documents (I think I can use the same list during upload and Edit). So, could you please give a suitable Bootstrap  example as shown on the image? Thanks a lot..

Comment: Sorry, This site is for helping you to resolve issues with your code, not a code writing service (and there are far too many ways to solve this). You need to at least make an effort to show what you have tried.